# Ununderstood type variance using kotlin variance

Tags: kotlin, generics

I'm using generics to not reuse code and I' running into a lack of understanding for type generics. I have a class Writer (java code from another library).

```
public class Writer<T>
```

A class FileWriter (java code from another library)

```
public class FileWriter<D>{

  FileWriter(Writer<D> writer){
    this.writer=writer
  }
  
  public void append(D datum){
  //Does something
  }
}
```

Now I'm initiating this in kotlin:

```
val writer = FileWriter(Writer(AGenratedJavaClassThatIMplementsSpecificRecord::class.java))
```

I can now call writer.append with AGenratedJavaClassThatIMplementsSpecificRecord(). It works just fine

I would like to pass this writer to a function.

```
funDoSomethingExtra(writer: FileWriter<in SpecificRecord>)
```

This gives me an error that I do not understand.

```
Type mismatch: inferred type is FileWriter<AGenratedJavaClassThatIMplementsSpecificRecord!>! but FileWriter<in SpecificRecord> was expected
```

Changing this to

```
funDoSomethingExtra(writer: FileWriter<out SpecificRecord>)
```

Makes writers.append give the error

```
Required Nothing, found AGenratedJavaClassThatIMplementsSpecificRecord.
```

Without the use of methods, all works fine. Which details Am I missing? It is probably something small,

Kind regards,
Jelmew

Answer (score 0):

This line of your code:

```
val writer = FileWriter(Writer(AGenratedJavaClassThatIMplementsSpecificRecord::class.java))
```

does not specify the type of the FileWriter, so it is inferred from your arguments to the constructors, so the type of `writer` is `FileWriter<AGenratedJavaClassThatIMplementsSpecificRecord>`.

Your signature `funDoSomethingExtra(writer: FileWriter<in SpecificRecord>)` is correct for calling a method on the `writer` that does something to a `SpecificRecord` or subtype of `SpecificRecord`. However, your

```
FileWriter<AGenratedJavaClassThatIMplementsSpecificRecord>
```

cannot be cast to a `FileWriter<in SpecificRecord>` because `AGenratedJavaClassThatIMplementsSpecificRecord` is a subtype of `SpecificRecord`, not a supertype. The compiler knows your file writer can consume `AGenratedJavaClassThatIMplementsSpecificRecord`, but it doesn't know it can consume the less-specific type `SpecificRecord`. There's the possibility of you calling some function of the subtype that doesn't exist in the supertype.

So to be able to pass your writer to this function, it needs to be a `FileWriter<SpecificRecord>` or `FileWriter<in SpecificRecord>`. You can't safely cast it after its type is already assigned, but you can assign it the proper type right at the declaration site instead of letting the compiler try to infer it:

```
val writer: FileWriter<SpecificRecord> = FileWriter(Writer(AGenratedJavaClassThatIMplementsSpecificRecord::class.java))
```

Comment: That still gives: Type mismatch: inferred type is Writer<AGenratedJavaClassThatIMplementsSpecificRecord>! but Writer<SpecificRecord> was expected

Comment: Oh, I think I see the problem. But I need to see the signature of the constructor of Writer that you're calling to know how it might be worked around.

Comment: public SpecificDatumWriter(Class<T> c)